# Carousel de bootstrap se visualiza mal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Estoy teniendo problemas con mi `Carousel` en Bootstrap.
Lo copie tal cual,descargué jquery,bootstrap.js tambien puse el `viewport`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .shine {}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="continer">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div id="carousel-ejemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="3" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="4" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img src="ten1.jpg" title="God of War" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img src="ten2.jpg" title="PUBG´S" width="928px" height="483px" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img src="ten3.jpg" title="Far Cry 5" width="928px" height="483px" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img src="ten4.jpg" title="Monster Hunter" width="928px" height="483px" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img src="ten5(yes).jpg" title="Fornite" width="928px" height="483px" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controles -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
        </a>









      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parecería que te falta por añadir un fichero JS (y puede que otro CSS) con el código del carrusel.

Comment: Fuera de tópico: Que significa .shine en tu css? Por otro lado entrando en tu problema y complementando lo que dice @AlvaroMontoro aparte de añardir los ficheros asociados a Carousel necesitas inicializarlo. El ejemplo más elementas sería: `$('.carousel').carousel()` para más información te sugiero revises: [bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). Venía a editar la pregunta pero ya hay una edición pendiente. jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer la documentación de Bootstrap: [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

En tu código hay un par de errores, vamos a revisarlos:

- El div que contiene tu carousel tiene de nombre de clase
  **"continer"**, cambialo por **"container".**
- Los elementos del **ol "carousel-indicators"** tienen todos la
  **clase "active"**, solo el **primero debe tenerla**, además te recomiendo 
  usar la etiqueta "ul" en vez de "ol"
- **Después** del "carousel-indicators" se **declara el "carousel-inner"** que
  es donde se crearán los "carousel-item" que serán los div que contengan las 
  imágenes que irán pasando en el carousel.
- **Solo el primer** "carousel-item" debe tener la clase "active".

El código del carousel podría quedar parecido a este:

```
<div id="carousel-ejemplo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-ejemplo" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
      <!-- Resto de elementos -->
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src=".ten1.jpg" title="God of War" />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src=".ten2.jpg" title="PUBG´S" />
      </div>

     <!-- Resto de imagenes. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Controles -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previo</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-ejemplo" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias Ferni me salvaste la vida te mando un saludo desde Victori